# profit maxmising for monoplistic competition

Tags: profit-maximization, profits, monopolistic-competition

Why the book says that for monoplistic competition, the profits is maximised at `MR = MC`, that is, when marginal cost equals marginal revenue? The two curve joins at some point, on its left side, marginal revenue is greater than marginal cost, isn't that better for the company? Because revenue exceeds the cost.

Comment: Hi! You are confusing some concepts, marginal revenue is not the same as revenue. Look up what it is. A simple numerical example should clear this up for you, try to find one on this SE or somewhere else online.